# Create exe file from kotlin multiplatform app in intellij IDE

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm facing a problem trying to export a Kotlin Multiplatform project using compose into one `.exe` file, that **doesn't need jre** to start on another computer.

I've already tried to create the `.msi` installer and I'm able to create a package distribution, but I want to have only one `.exe` file that I can launch on another PC directly.

Is creating such executable possible? If yes, how can I create one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-gradle.html#build-and-run-the-application) will help.

From the documentation above:

### Use Gradle to generate the .kexe file.

From the root project directory, run the build command:

```
gradle nativeBinaries
```

This command creates the build/bin/native directory with two
directories inside: `debugExecutable` and `releaseExecutable`. They contain corresponding binary files.

### Run / locate your .kexe

By default, the name of the binary file is the same as the project directory. To run the project, execute the following command:

```
build/bin/native/debugExecutable/<project_name>.kexe
```

*Note: You will have a `.kexe` file, but it will work as fine as a `.exe` file.*